# How to calculate count for duplicated Item along with there status

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
_dataDetails = {
    name : test1 ,
    status : found,
    other : []
}
{
    name : test1 ,
    status : found,
    other : []
}
{
    name : test1 ,
    status : Not found,
    other : []
}
{
    name : test2 ,
    status : found,
    other : []
}etc ........
```

I want to calculate the count for found and not found for each names.

```
For example:
test1 
found:2
notfound :1

test2 
found:1
notfound :0
```

may code

```
var _data = []
var index = -1;
for ( var _i = 0; _i < _data.length; _i++ )
{
    if ( _data[_i][0] == _dataDetails[i].name ) { index = _i; }
}


if ( index >= 0 )
{
    if ( _dataDetails[i].status == 'found' )
    {
        _data[index][1][0]++;
    }
    else
    {
        _data[index][1][1]++;
    }
}
else
{
    if ( _dataDetails[i].result == 'Detected' )
    {
        _data.push([_dataDetails[i].name, [1, 0]]);
    }
    else
    {
        _data.push([_dataDetails[i].name, [0, 1]]);
    }
}
```

Here I am getting count doubled (instead of 10 it will give 20). Please suggest .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
    _dataDetails = [{
        name : "test1" ,
        status : "found",
        other : []
    },
    {
        name : "test1" ,
        status : "found",
        other : []
    },
    {
        name : "test1" ,
        status : "Not found" ,
        other : []
    },
    {
        name :"test2" ,
        status : "found",
        other : []
    }]

    var results={};
    _dataDetails.forEach ( function (o,i) {
        if(!results[o.name]) { 
    results[o.name] = {} ;
    results[o.name].found = 0;
    results[o.name].notfound = 0;
    }
        if (o.status === "found" ) {
    results[o.name].found++}
       else if (o.status === "Not found" ) {results[o.name].notfound++}
    });

    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(results).forEach(function(prop) {
    console.log( prop + "  found : " + results[prop].found + " ,  not found: "+ results[prop].notfound);
    });
```

See here: http://jsbin.com/kavesu/edit?js,console

Comment: Thanks this also giving same result for me with real data ,so it might be some other issue our both codes function similar ,Thank you very much

Comment: @prash Hmm., could you post the real data, if its not **sensitive** to http://pastebin.com .

Comment: i mean logic is  correct ,it could be some other data issue ,nothing to do with our code it seems

Comment: @prash Where are you getting the data from? And how did you know it 's doubled?  Maybe the data got duplicated?  I cant say much without seeing the data.

Comment: i am checking the count by running a script in DB ,might be that script is wrong

Answer (score 2):

you can code like this

```
var _dataDetails = [{
    name : test1 ,
    status : found,
    other : []
}
{
    name : test1 ,
    status : found,
    other : []
}
{
    name : test1 ,
    status : Not found,
    other : []
}
{
    name : test2 ,
    status : found,
    other : []
}];

var counter = {};

for(index in _dataDetails) {
    var dt = _dataDetails[index];
    if(counter[dt.name]) {
        counter[dt.name] += 1;
    } else {
        counter[dt.name] = 1;
    }
}
console.log(counter);
```

Comment: How is _dataDetails a valid Array? Thats a SyntaxError right there.

Comment: @raghavendra it's missing commas between the objects. Aside from that, this will work fine.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah. though the for in could be replaced by something designed for iterating over Arrays

Comment: thanks ,but i want the count of found and not found not for only names

Comment: for exampme test1 
found:2
notfound :1  I am able to get this using my above code but somehow it is showing doubled